# Abort "for", when after array is empty

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, mysqli

i have the var $products who reads the id and twelve products from a mysql row in a array. No i want that only the fields who have text will be displayd. I wrote it with a "for" and it works, but how can i tell the code to stop, after the array is getting empty? "p" is to generate the db field name who is p1, p2 and so on.

```
for($i=1; $i < count($products); $i++)
{
echo "<div>Produkt ".$i":</div>
<div>".$products["p".$i]</div>"
}
```

Comment: yoy can break execution (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) but it should not start if loop is empty, so SQL response needs to have only data that valid to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i < count($products); $i++)
{
if($products["p".$i] !=""){
    echo "<div>Produkt ".$i.":</div>";
    echo "<div>".$products["p".$i]."</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Woow, exactly this! You were so fast, i can accept your answer in 8 Minutes! It fits perfectly! Thank you very much!